# Essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise from Gamelin.

If $f(z)$ is a complex function with a not removable singularity in $ z_{0} \ $, then $e^{f(z)} \ $ has an essential singularity in $z_{0} $.

Any hint?

Comment: $f(z)$ is complex, I guess...

Comment: @draks: yes, f is complex

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445160/z-0-non-removable-singularity-of-f-rightarrow-z-0-essential-singularity-of/1029929#1029929

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your function $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ write $(z-z_0)^m f(z) = p(z) + (z-z_0)^m h(z)$ where $h$ is holomorphic and $p$ is a polynomial of degree $<m$.  Then $f(z)= \displaystyle \frac{p(z)}{(z-z_0)^m} + h(z)$.  Now take $e$ to both sides, note that $e^{h(z)}$ is holomorphic, and use the power series expansion of the exponential to show that $e^{\frac{p(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}}$ has infinitely many negative powers of $z-z_0$.

Comment: Ok if f has a pole at z0  your solution is correct, but if f has an essential singularity in z0  ?

Comment: @stef That's the easy case. :)

Comment: How to show that this expansion necessarily has an infinitude of summands and that it cannot have some sort of telescoping series canceling the terms out...?

Comment: @Parsa Even easy, could your elaborate it ?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't looked at this stuff in a while, but [Casorati-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) might help.

In particular there is a sequence $(z_k)$ converging to $z_0$ such that $(f(z_k))$ converges to $w_0$ (this is page 175 of your book). Since $w_0$ is arbitrary can you think of a particular value that helps solve this problem?