# If $f$ is entire can $e^f$ have a pole at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Didn't see any like this in the similar questions, so hopefully it isn't a repeat. There was a question on a past qual that asked if $f$ is entire, can $e^f$ have a pole at infinity. I think the answer is going to be no. But would like confirmation. If possible it would be much appreciate if someone could tell me why my logic is correct or incorrect.

Suppose $e^f$ has a pole at infinity. Clearly we cannot have $f$ be constant, hence as a consequence of Louisville's theorem we must have $\infty$ be either a pole or an essential singularity of $f$. If $\infty$ were essential, then we could find a sequence $z_n\to\infty$ such that $f(z_n)\to c$ for some constant $c$. Then $e^{f(z_n)}\to e^c$ and so $\lim_{z\to \infty}e^{f(z)}\not=\infty$ and $e^f$ does not have a pole at $\infty$.

The last case we have to consider is were $f$ has a pole at infinity. Let $g(w)=f(1/w)$. Let $D$ an exterior domain, and define $1/D=\{1/z:z\in D\}$. Then as $g$ has a pole inside $1/D$ it follows that either
$$\int_{\partial 1/D} d\arg(g)\not=0\text{ }(*)$$
or
$$\int_{\partial 1/D}d\arg(g)=0\text{ }(**)$$
If $(*)$ then by the argument principle modulo $2\pi$ it follows that $\arg(g)$ takes on every value in $[0,2\pi)$, in particular we can choose $w\in 1/D$ with $g(w)\in i\mathbb{R}$.

If $(**)$ then as $g$ has a pole in $1/D$ at $0=1/\infty$ it follows that $g$ must have a zero in $1/D$ as
$$\int_{\partial1/D}d\arg(g)=\#\{\text{ zeros of }g\text{ in }1/D\}-\#\{\text{ poles of }g\text{ in }1/D\}$$
In this case we have $g(w)=0\in i\mathbb{R}$ for some $w\in 1/D$.

We conclude that regardless of our situation we can choose $w\in 1/D$ with $g(w)\in i\mathbb{R}$. As a consequence we can choose $z\in D$ with $f(z)\in i\mathbb{R}$. Well then as $D$ was an arbitrary exterior domain we can choose $z_n\to\infty$ with $f(z)\in i\mathbb{R}$, so $|e^{f(z_n)}|=1$, and we cannot have
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{f(z)}=\infty$$
Consequently $e^f$ does not have a pole at infinity.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445160/42969 for some simpler proofs.

Comment: in this case $e^f$ would need to be a polynomial and that is not possible; in general (for the local problem near an essential singularity), one can just take absolute values of $e^f$ and get that $\Re f \to \infty$ and show that is not compatible with $f$ having an essenbtial singularity there because then the image of $f$ near the singularity avoids a half plane for example

Comment: If $e^f$ has a pole or a zero at $a$ then $f$ is logarithmic ie. not analytic on $0<|z-a|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for the last part: Suppose $f$ has a pole at $\infty,$ i.e., $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial. Let $r>0.$ Then $f(\{|z|\le r\})$$ $$ \subset \{|z|\le s\}$ for some $s>0.$

Now $f,$ being a nonconstant polynomial, maps $\mathbb C$ onto $\mathbb C.$ Therefore $f(\{|z|> r\})$ contains $\{|z|> s\}.$ This implies $f(\{|z|> r\})$ contains the horizontal strip $\{x+iy: 2s\le y \le 2s + 2\pi\}.$ Since $e^w$ maps any such strip onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},$ $e^f$ maps $\{|z|> r\}$ onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}.$ This is true for all $r>0,$ and implies $e^f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty.$