# Proof Verification: Show that if $f(z)$ is a non-constant entire function , then $g(z)=exp(f(z))$ has essential singularity in $z=\infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Show that if $f(z)$ is a non-constant entire function , then $g(z)=exp(f(z))$ has essential singularity in $z=\infty$.

**This question has been answered in the link** Thanks!

My approach: Let $f$ analytic (then $f$ has a series), then $exp(f(z))$ is analytic. Then

$$exp(f(\frac{1}{w}))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}(f(\frac{1}{w}))^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\frac{a_{m}}{w^m}})^{n}}$$

We can see that $exp(f(\frac{1}{w}))$ has essential singularity in $w=0$, since there exist negative coefficients. So, $exp(f(z))$ has essential singularity in $w=0$. Is this right? Thanks!

Comment: Your argument is not valid. This question has been asked many times. Apply the following to $f(\frac 1 z)$ (with $z_0=0$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127168/essential-singularity

Comment: But why, my argument is not valid?? I prove this is a essential singularity. Thanks!

Comment: You have to prove that there are infinitely many non-zero terms in negative powers of $w$ to say that function has an essential singularity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But it was I proof, my serie has infinitely many terms in negative powers of w.

Comment: But you need to show that it has infinitely many NONZERO terms....What if, after opening the brackets all the negative coefficients cancel?

Comment: @N.S. But is impossible that the negative coefficientes cancels, after we expand the summation.

Comment: @Johnny.c Why? If it is impossible, you should be able to prove it, just try ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the singularity at infinity were removable,  then $f$ would be bounded.   Then by Liouville's theorem is constant. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/223294) answer.

So it appears we can get that it's a non-removable singularity.   But as @N.S. points out, it could still be a pole.  To rule that out, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127178/403337).

Comment: I saw those answer, but my approach is correct? Thanks

Comment: I think it's another way of saying it.

Comment: What if the singularity was a pole?

Comment: I guess I overlooked that possibility.

Comment: Apparently the link you included above has an answer.